# Why cannot bind data to telerik kendo dropdownlist

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I cannot bind the data from my database to telerik kendo Drop Down list.
When i run the code the drop down list just showing blank like this and cannot be click.

[image]

Model

```
public class CountryModel
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public string CountryDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        private ActionResult GetCountry()
        {
            var countryList = _registerBS.GetCountry();
            return Json(countryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("country")
          .OptionLabel("hello")
          .DataTextField("CountryDesc")
          .DataValueField("CountryCode")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCountry", "Register");
              });
          })
                )
```

Logic to communicate with database

```
        public IEnumerable<CountryModel> GetCountry()
        {
            var query = (from country in _countryRepo.GetAllActive()
                         select new CountryModel
                         {
                             CountryCode = country.Country_CODE,
                             CountryDesc = country.Country_DESC
                         });

            return query;
        }
```

Comment: Any error on the JavaScript console?

Comment: How far have you debugged? Hitting the controller? Filling the list? Console errors? Too many possibilities without more info.